# PostgreSQL9.6.10 the output of vacuumdb is right?

Tags: linux, database, postgresql

PostgreSQL7.0

input command: vacuumdb -z  XXX
Outputs:
VACUUM  →Everything went well.

PostgreSQL8.3.7

input command: vacuumdb -z  XXX
Outputs:
nothing →　Everything went well.

PostgreSQL9.6.10

input command:vacuumdb -z

outputs:
vacuumdb: vacuuming database "XXXX"　→　the reslut of vacuumdb  command is ok？

Comment: What did the manual tell you? And why don't you use --verbose to get more detailed information? And version 9.6, are you sure?

Comment: Are you really using Postgres 7.0 and 8.3? Those are even more ancient than the also no longer supported 9.6 version.

Comment: yes my version is  9.6.10  .i can not get  more information from the manual .